# Getting "Must be a POST request" while pushing to third party website

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

I am trying to push data to a third party website from Netsuite. The same push script works well in sandbox, but when moved to production it returns "Must be a POST request" error. The following code I have used in both sandbox and production. Is there any specific function exists to fix the issue? Can anyone please help me to rectify this issue. Thanks.

[image: Push to website]

Comment: much easier to help if you supply the actual code rather than a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your test was client side;

This API has two different forms. On the server there is no callback parameter so just remove the null callback:

```
var response = nlapiRequestURL(portalURL, myJSONText, headers);
```